# Using setEnabled() or setDisabled()

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, widget

If I want to disable a button from being clicked while a GUI function is calculating, is there any difference between using `setEnabled(false)` or `setDisabled(true)`?

I am just curious why there are two functions that seem to have the same purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They both modify the same property. `setDisabled` is just for convenience, for example if you use it as a slot for a toggled signal.

Using `setEnabled` and `setDisabled` you can either enable or disable a widget by toggling a button/action/checkbox without needing an intermediate slot to invert the value.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that there are two separate functions is that they are slots, so depending to what signal you are connecting and what behavior you expect you can connect to one of them. They are functionally the same.

Answer (score 0):

There's almost no difference, but you should use setEnabled in this case since it's more direct. setDisabled looks like this:

```
void QWidget::setDisabled(bool disabled){ this->setEnabled(!disabled); }
```